# Re-Instantiating static field after deserialization is bad practice?

Tags: java, serialization, static, field

I have a couple of fields in my code that I've declared `static` for simplicity, they are shared by MANY different classes in many different parts of each class' code and it is way easier (and less error prone) to make them readable by each single class without using reflection. The problem is with serialization, since, obviously it doesn't save their state. 
Now, my question is: Is making a function inside the serialization methods to save the state of those fields to a non-static variable and then re-loading the state after deserialization bad practice?

Comment: Have you thought about using a Singleton?

Comment: The problem is with references, not with the instance itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `static` references of variables in the non-static content. So you have to change your design to make beans in place of static variables.

Comment: This doesn't help me much.